# Heat Equation on $[0,T] \times \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, heat-equation

I'm currently looking for a complete proof of a classical result (very useful for viscosity methods) and surprisingly all the references I can get study the heat equation on bounded domain.

Do you know where I can find a complete proof of such a result :
There exists a unique solution $u$ to the problem

$\left\{
\begin{array}{rcll}
\partial_t u(t,x) - \eta \Delta u(t,x) &=& f(t,x)&\qquad\text{on } ]0,T]\times \mathbb{R}^n \\
u(0,x) &=& u_0(x)&\qquad\text{on } \mathbb{R}^n
\end{array}
\right.$

with $f\in L^2(0,T;L^2(\mathbb{R}^n))$, $u_0 \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\eta>0$ fixed and furthermore $u\in L^2(0,T;H^2(\mathbb{R}^n))$ and $\partial_t u \in L^2(0,T;L^2(\mathbb{R}^n))$.

Thank you

Comment: Duhamel formula could be the tool to prove such a result, by a contraction mapping argument.  http://wiki.math.toronto.edu/DispersiveWiki/index.php/Duhamel%27s_formula

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fourier transform in $x$ gets you there:
$
\dot v+\eta\vert\xi\vert^2 v=g(t,\xi),\quad v(0)=v_0,
$
so that
$$
v(t,\xi)=e^{-t\eta \vert\xi\vert^2} v_0(\xi)+\int_0^te^{-(t-s)\eta \vert\xi\vert^2} g(s,\xi) ds.
$$
Since $\iint_0^T\vert g(t,\xi)\vert^2 dtd\xi<+\infty$ and 
$\int\vert v_0(\xi)\vert^2 d\xi<+\infty$,
you get
$$
\iint_0^Te^{-2t\eta \vert\xi\vert^2} \vert \xi\vert^2\vert v_0(\xi)\vert^2 dt d\xi\le  \int\frac{[e^{-2t\eta \vert \xi\vert^2}]^{t=0}_{t=T}}{2\eta}\vert v_0(\xi)\vert^2 d\xi\le
(2\eta)^{-1}\int\vert v_0(\xi)\vert^2 d\xi<+\infty,
$$
and similarly with $H=\mathbf 1_{\mathbb R_+}$
$$
\vert \xi\vert^2\int H(t-s)e^{-(t-s)\eta \vert \xi\vert^2} g(s)H(s) ds= \vert \xi\vert^2 H(t)e^{-t\eta \vert \xi\vert^2} \ast g(t)H(t)
$$
with $L^2$ norm (in $t$) bounded above by
$$
\vert \xi\vert^2 (\int_0^T\vert g(t,\xi)\vert^2 dt)^{1/2}\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-t\eta \vert \xi\vert^2} dt
=\eta^{-1}(\int_0^T\vert g(t,\xi)\vert^2 dt)^{1/2}
$$
and the square of the $L^2$ norm (in $t,\xi$) is bounded above by
$$
\eta^{-2}\iint_0^T\vert g(t,\xi)\vert^2 dtd\xi<+\infty.
$$ 
The last statement on $\dot v$
comes from the equation and the previous results.

Answer (score 1):

See *Linear and quasilinear equations of parabolic type*, 1968, by O.A. Ladyzenskaja, V.A. Solonnikov, and N.N. Ural'ceva, Theorem 6.1 in Chapter III.

See also Theorem 9.1, Chapter IV, in the same book, for integrability exponents different than 2:

For $q >1$, if $f\in L^q(0,T\times \Omega)$ and $u_0\in W^{2-2/q,q}$, there exists a solution $u$, moreover $u\in L^q(0,T;W^{2,q}(\Omega))$ and $\partial_tu\in L^q(0,T;L^q(\Omega))$.